# How to use Grails WebService Stub?

Tags: grails, groovy, wsdl

I have a wsdl file with me and i generated stubs using IntelliJ idea which uses axis2 to generate Java classes from WSDL.

I am using Grails-Ws-Client  plugin to use the wsdl file. The plugin works fine and i can run the temperature conversion program using [www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL](http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL).

Now the Client says that he won't be able to directly expose his wsdl and i have to use stubs. He has replaced the location URL in wsdl with some dummy url ....

Can you please provide me some reference to understand this concept ? How can i call any method exposed by this webservice ?

Any help in this direction will be highly appreciated.

PS: Here is the location tag specified in wsdl file.

soap:address location="https://somePortal/portal.asmx"

Comment: You are using the WS-Client so trying to expose a webservice with that will never work.

Comment: Nope. I am using WS-Client to consume the webservice.

Answer (score 0):

Make the WSDL local. The stubs you crated can be pointed to the local WSDL instead the remote WSDL.